# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 8 runtime exception in my array sorting code

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I was trying to create an array sorting program in Java. So I created this method and tried to execute it by calling it from another function . But I am getting this *"ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 8"* runtime exception. So how do I fix it?

```
class arrayfunc {
    int[] ascend(int[] p) {
        int x = p.length;
        for (int i = 0; i <= (x - 1); i++) {
            int l = p[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= x; j++) {
                int f = p[j];
                if (f > l) {
                    int k = p[i];
                    p[i] = p[j];
                    p[j] = k;
                }
            }
        }
        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you first please indent your code correctly, name your variable better than i,j and p...

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is an exception saying that you try to access a table out of his limit (example tab[10] for an array of 10 element). Please check your loop condition

Comment: could you provide how you call the method, and a sample input? i am not gettin an outOfBound, despite the fact that it ignores the first number.

Comment: it's bubble sort. It shouldn't crash.Every index is between 0 and length-1.  I think it's outside.

Comment: first code was good !

Answer (score 1):

Your inner loop

```
for(int j=i+1;j<=(x);j++)
```

should probably be

```
for(int j=i+1;j<=(x-1);j++)
```

otherwise you will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException here:

```
int f=p[j];
```

when your index variable j reaches the value of x

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<=` by `<` in both your `for` loops.

By the way, Java will never win a code golf. You can expand your text...